# Set parent's state from child

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

My custom component should pass data to parent which is react-admin `<Create>`
I have came across some questions already and found that I can't simply set state from child to parent.

The problem is that this component should work like the default react-admin components (ex. ). It means when I submit the form It gets data from that component.

I have already tried `addField()`

This is my custom component (child):

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import { DataService } from '../routes/api';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { resources as rsrc } from '../resources';

const divStyle = {
  marginTop: '16px',
  marginBottom: '8px',
};

const inputStyle = {
  width: '256px',
}

export default class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectOptions: [],
      selectedValues: [],
      selectedValue: null,
    };
  }

  getRoles() {
   // get data from api
  }

  getAllOptions() {
    // get some additional data from API
  }

  createRelationRecord(id) {
    // create relation record (for ex. User's Role)
  }

  deleteRelationRecord(id) {
    // delete relation record
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.getRoles();
      this.getAllOptions();
  }

  renderSelectOptions = () => {
    return this.state.selectOptions.map((dt, i) => (
      <MenuItem key={dt.id} value={dt.id}>
        {dt.value}
      </MenuItem>
    ));
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: event.target.value });

    // If record doesn't exist
    if (this.state.selectedValue != event.nativeEvent.target.dataset.value) {
      this.createRelationRecord(event.nativeEvent.target.dataset.value);
    }

    if (this.state.selectedValues.includes(Number(event.nativeEvent.target.dataset.value))) {
      this.deleteRelationRecord(event.nativeEvent.target.dataset.value);
    } else {
      this.createRelationRecord(event.nativeEvent.target.dataset.value);
    }
  };

  selectboxType() {
    if (this.props.multiple) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  getSelected() {
    if (this.selectboxType()) {
      return this.state.selectedValues;
    }
    return this.state.selectedValue;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor={this.props.label}>{this.props.label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
              multiple={this.selectboxType()}
              style={inputStyle}
              value={this.getSelected()}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              {this.renderSelectOptions()}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent (create form):

```
export const ServerCreate = props => (
   <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
         <TextInput source="Name" validate={required()} />
         <ReferrenceSelectBox label="ServerType" multiple={false} source="ServerTypeId" reference="ServerType"></ReferrenceSelectBox>
         <TextInput source="Barcode" validate={required()} />
      </SimpleForm>
   </Create>
);
```

It works with `handleChange` to achieve the data update. Now I need to save the selected data in Create form, but handleChange will not help me, because the object is not created yet and I cannot set attribute of non-existent record.

So my question is how can I pass value/values from my component to Create? How to set parent's state?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServerCreate` doesn't have any state, but if it did, you need to pass a function which can update its state to the child component as a prop.

Generally speaking, you should probably [lift the state higher up the component tree](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: If ServerCreate doesn't have state, how can I pass data from custom component do create?

Comment: Yeah this is all contrained by your use of `react-admin` which applies its own magic, that I'm not familiar with. Are you trying to create a custom input component? According to the docs: "You’ll have to rely on redux-form’s <Field> component, so as to handle the value update cycle.": https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component